# Convert number to word

Tags: output-formatting, natural-language

I have a big number like: 123 456 789. Now I'll to writ it like this

> 123 million 456 thousand 789

I've search on the internet but nothing found that works.

How can you do that?
Thanks.

Comment: [Related1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-express-an-integer-number-in-english-words), [Related2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1398398/353410)

Comment: **To the close voters:** the questions are similar but the desired output is different, permitting different approaches.  I will not overrule a Close but please consider this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Mathematica 10* introduces [`IntegerName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html):

> - `IntegerName[n]` gives a string containing the full English name of the integer n.
> - `IntegerName[n,"type"]` gives a string of the specified type.
>
> Possible types include:
>
> - `"DigitsWords"`  a combination of three-digit numbers and words
> - `"Words"`    using only words
> - `"Approximate"`  the first few digits plus thousands, millions, etc.
> - `"ApproximateWords"` the first few digits as words plus thousands, etc.

Example:

```
IntegerName[123456789]
```

> ```
> "123 million 456 thousand 789"
> ```

---

[ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov)
 comments that small numbers are converted to words:

```
IntegerName[84]
```

> ```
> "eighty‐four"
> ```

If this is a problem one could use:

```
fn = If[Abs[#] < 1000, IntegerString, IntegerName][#] &;

fn /@ {51, 781, 25483}
```

> ```
> {"51", "781", "25 thousand 483"}
> ```

Comment: Hah this is great I love it.  Should make an expression-to-English translator.  "E to the i theta tensor product etc..."

Comment: It exists in audio:  `Speak[Exp[I \[Theta]]]` or `Speak[BarChart[{3, 4, 5}]]` and turn up your speakers.

Comment: And in text:  `SpokenString[Exp[I \[Theta]]]` or `SpokenString[BarChart[{3,4,5}]]`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This is magic.

Comment: Do you know how to deal with shot numbers? `IntegerName[123, "DigitsWords"]` returns `one hundred twenty-three`. I'm not sure that it's desired output.

Comment: @ybeltukov Okay.  See update.

Comment: Oddly (to me), `"Approximate"` and `"ApproximateWords"` do not round. For example, `IntegerName[123987654, "Approximate"]` returns `"123 million \[Ellipsis]"`.

Answer (score 7):

You people with your fancy version 10 have it too easy.

```
 StringJoin@Reverse@MapIndexed[ToString[#] <>
       {"", " thousand ", " million ", " billion ", " trillion" }[[First@#2]] &, 
    Reverse@(FromDigits /@ 
      Partition[PadLeft[#, 3 - Mod[#, 3, 1] + # &@Length@#] , 3])] &@   
         IntegerDigits[123456789]
```

> "123 million 456 thousand 789"

Comment: As a long-time version 7 user I always like seeing backward-compatible answers. +1

Answer (score 4):

In version 9 and earlier you can do it with `Riffle` and `IntegerDigits[...,1000]`:

```
name[n_Integer] := If[n < 0, "minus ", ""] <> Riffle[ToString /@ IntegerDigits[n, 1000], 
     {" thousand ", " million ", " billion ", " trillion "}, {-2, 2, -2}]

{#, name@#} & /@ ((-12)^Range@10) // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  It would be even better if this handled negative numbers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just added a prefix depending on the sign

Comment: nice, i knew there was a better way than what i cooked up.

Comment: I notice you chose "minus" whereas `IntegerName` uses "negative" -- is the latter an American English thing?  p.s. I think it would be arguably better to put the `ToString /@` inside `Riffle`.

Comment: May be. My knowledge of English is not enough. There are some discussions: [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157127), [MO.SE](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24674). Of course, `ToString` of `String` looks strange :-)