# Convert a numerical expression to words

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion

I would like to convert algebraic sums of the form `8+1-3` into words, obtaining `"eight plus one minus three"`.

I have tried using `IntegerName`, but it does not work for me, it computes the result

```
IntegerName[8 + 1 - 3, "Words"]
```

> "six"

I have tried sing `HoldForm` or `Unevaluated` in conjunction with `SpokenString`, but no joy. Grateful if anyone can help!

ETA - note that my question is different from the one asked here:
[Convert number to word](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73717/convert-number-to-word/73836?newreg=9063772b66884901abf1a247024ed54c)
where only one number, not an expression, needed converting.

Answer (score 4):

```
SpokenString[HoldForm[8 + 1 - 3]]
```

> "8 plus 1 minus 3"

```
% // StringReplace[n : NumberString :> IntegerName @ ToExpression @ n]
```

> "eight plus one minus three"

Comment: Surprisingly `IntegerName` will handle `8.5` and friends too.